# Flutter: most efficient option for storing simple data

Tags: database, flutter

I want to store simple data that I can add to and edit. This might also include things like settings and time data. What is the best, easiest and most efficient way of doing this for a flutter app?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and lightest way to achieve this is the sharedprefrences.
see this: 
[using shared prefrences in flutter](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/using-sharedpreferences-in-flutter-251755f07127)

Answer (score 0):

One way is shared preferences [package](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences).

Usage;

1 - Open pubspec.yaml and add shared_preferences as a dependency

```
dependencies:
    shared_preferences: ^0.5.4
```

2 - Reading/Updating data

```
toggleSound() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  int currentData = (prefs.getInt('soundOn') ?? 1);
  await prefs.setInt('soundOn', currentData==1?0:1);
}
```